# Haskell - How do I write an idiomatic and efficient loop?

Tags: haskell

I'm relatively new to Haskell, so I am working through some old Advent of Code problems to familiarize myself with the language.

However, I got stuck on 2017 day 17, part two.
I've tried three solutions to this problem.

(Edit: reduced the code block to a clearer example)

The following solution is something I would expect to work moderately efficiently:

```
run :: IO()
run = do
    print "Starting:"
    print (iteration''' 0 1 3 0 50000000)

iteration''' :: Int -> Int -> Int -> Int -> Int -> (Int, Int, Int, Int)
iteration''' cp cv ss zv 0 = (cp, cv, ss, zv)
iteration''' cp cv ss zv count = iteration''' ncp ncv ss nzv (count - 1)
    where
        ncp = ((cp + ss) `mod` cv) + 1
        nzv = if ncp == 1 then cv else zv
        ncv = cv + 1
```

The problem is that all three are horribly inefficient, both memory-wise and CPU-wise.
The equivalent C-code would be something like the following (completing very quickly).

```
int stepSize = 3;
int zv = 0;
int position = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 50000000; i++) {
    position = (position + stepSize) % i;
    if (position == 0) zv = i;
}
```

I assumed `iteration'''` would be able to compile to something similar - but it eats up gigabytes of memory and loops for a long time.

To summarize my question - what is an idiomatic way to "solve this problem efficiently" in Haskell? Why is it eating up so much heap space when there is no actual object turnover necessary?

I am compiling using ghc (cabal).

Comment: Just a few quick tips: start by compiling with -O2. Also, if you are using GHCi, don't -- it's not meant to be fast, instead compile to executable and run that. Then, as an experiment try making the `Int` fields of the spinlock strict, e.g. `{ ... , currentValue :: ! Int , ... }`. Maybe some more strictness "bangs" can help, but it's hard to tell quickly.

Comment: Thanks! No luck though - no discernable difference when using -O2 flags with cabal.
I reduced the code in the post to make it more understandable.

Comment: This is almost certainly a strictness issue. Try ```ncp `seq` nzv `seq` ncv `seq` iteration''' ncp ncv ss nzv (count-1)```, or equivalently, `iteration''' !cp !cv !ss !zv count = ...` with `BangPatterns` turned on.

Comment: You were completely correct, the original solution ate my entire CPU and at least 5GB of RAM, resulting in a crash after a few minutes of runtime - adding the bangs reduced the time to about a second. Thanks.

Do you have any literature or links about how to determine when to force strictness?

Comment: There is no fast rule, but when returning a container (tuple/list/map/...) of simple data like `Int`s, it might be useful to force the `Int`s so to avoid returning a tuple of thunks. GHC can not optimize this automatically (it does so in some other cases). Indeed, the caller might only demand one of the ints in the returned tuple, hence GHC can not assume all will be needed, hence GHC must not evaluate the non-demanded ints to follow lazy semantics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For completeness, as answered by Daniel Wagner and chi:

The problem in the stated code was strictness (implicitly a large amount of lazily evaluated ints resulted in a large amount of overhead).

This method is a lot faster (adding the `BangPatterns` header)

```
iteration''' :: Int -> Int -> Int -> Int -> Int -> (Int, Int, Int, Int)
iteration''' !cp !cv !ss !zv 0 = (cp, cv, ss, zv)
iteration''' !cp !cv !ss !zv !count = iteration''' ncp ncv ss nzv (count - 1)
    where
        ncp = ((cp + ss) `mod` cv) + 1
        nzv = if ncp == 1 then cv else zv
        ncv = cv + 1
```

I think the implication is that this is the idiomatic way to write (some) performant code as well!

Comment: I believe you do not need to repeat the bangs in the second equation, since the arguments were already forced by the first one. Even `!count` is unnecessary since we compared with `0` earlier. (Still, it does not hurt to add them anyway.)

Comment: I sort of suspected that this would be the case. However, out of curiosity, what version is considered more readable? (I like that you can immediately determine that the arguments are strictly evaluated just by looking at the line in question and not depending on the implied strictness from the other lines)

Comment: I can't decide which one is more readable. Perhaps the most readable way is to add a third line at the very top `iteration''' !_cp !_cv !_ss !_zv !_count | False = undefined -- make args strict` and forget about strictness elsewhere. This is a "trick" that is sometimes used to quickly turn any function into a strict one without touching the previous code. I'm not a huge fan of that, but it is kind of clear, especially with the comment, and separates the strictness requirement from the actual code.